# Создать папку на External sd card

Tags: android, memory

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь создать папку для хранения фоток с камеры приложения. Использую код:

```
File checkDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Albums/Application/Images");

if(checkDir.exists()) {
 Log.v(LOG_TAG, "directory exist");
} else {
 Log.v(LOG_TAG, "directory NOT exist");
 checkDir.mkdirs();
 Log.v(LOG_TAG, "directory create");
}
```

НО все равно папка создается не на ext_sd (флешке), а на внутренней памяти телефона (sdcard0).

Уже и писал абсолютный путь, но он отрабатывает корень "/" как sdcard0, а дальше иерархия по моему пути. Бред какой-то выходит.

Как решить ситуацию ?

P.S.: в приложении планируется делать фотоснимки и хранить их для отображения в этом же приложении. Желание хранить на флешке, так как у нее объем больше.

Comment: @web_alex, прописан

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`?

Comment: Да, разрешение есть.

Comment: ===> Я попытался узнать из лога состояние и путь к памяти.




Log.d(LOG_TAG, "sd path: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "sd path: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());




Результат:

09-11 12:30:12.300: D/myLogs(5042): sd path: mounted

09-11 12:30:12.300: D/myLogs(5042): sd path: /storage/sdcard0

Comment: @web_alex, ваш код верен, и он создает папку на сд карте.

Comment: я тестирую код на htc desire 600, а Вы ? 
Данный девайс не root'ован.

Comment: @web_alex, nexus 4 и galaxy tab 4. В файловом менеджере вижу созданную папку `/sdcard/Albums/Application/Images`.

Comment: То есть все равно создало на внутренней(internal, как и мне), а не на внешней(external_sdcard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я никогда не юзал htc desire 600, но (как подсказывает мой опыт использования xperia) по всей видимости девайс имеет внутреннюю память разбитую на 2 раздела:
-внутренний системный раздел,
-второй раздел, смонтированный как cdcard (который идет из коробки),
 + слот для внешней cd карты, куда вы собственно хотите писать (3 раздел).

Поэтому что в данном случае, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() возвращает путь к встроенной в телефон карте памяти (2-му разделу).

Путь к "удаляемой" карте, можно получить только начиная с версии 4.4 с помощью `getExternalFilesDirs`, до 4.4 официальной поддержки "removable storage" нет.
вот некоторая [инфа](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html)

Comment: То есть для API < 4.4 запись фоток на карту памяти закрыта на 1оо% ?
Или может хитрость есть какая-то ?

Comment: У каждого девайса путь может отличаться. Посмотреть можно немного [тут][1]. 
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976982/removable-storage-external-sdcard-path-by-manufacturers

Comment: @gcoder, кошмар какой!! Ввели бы стандарт один для всех и было бы ок. 
Хардкодом прописал и норм. 
Можно, конечно, попробовать прописать switch с параметрами и для каждого производителя свой путь, но это будет хардкод всех хардкодов.